# jquery domain and url validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using following regex to test if url is valid...

```
var pattern = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

It returns `true` for following urls...

```
http://google.com
http://google.co.uk
http://something.google.xyz
http://something.google.co.uk
```

But i want to allow plain domains as well for example...

```
google.com
google.nyc
google.co.uk
sub.google.com
```

Please help to modify this. Thanks

Comment: I find this site useful when using regex - http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: @piggy good place to learn, i want this regex modified

Comment: try this one
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/

Comment: @IsmailKuruca Thanks for modified regex, its working as expected, i had fewer tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to test that the URL is valid and aren't picking out specific parts you could use something simpler.

`(https?:\/\/)?\w+\.`

Comment: @seoppc added a new regex for url validation only

Comment: @Quentin `google.com `is a valid domain name not just `google`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one, also applies for subdomains.

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```